# tinyxml how to work with it when multiple xml files?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

i have an xml like this

```
<xml http://......>
<value>
<name>me</name>
<age>12</age>
</value>
<value>
<name>kk</name>
<age>1</age>
</value>
</xml>
```

this xml is in a string value called s;
i did:

```
const char *data =s.c_str();

TiXmlDocument doc;
doc.Parse((const char*)data, 0, TIXML_ENCODING_UTF8);
const std::string m_name;

TiXmlHandle handle(&doc);
TiXmlElement* section;
section = handle.FirstChild("xml").FirstChild("value").FirstChild("name").Element();
if (section) {//code }
```

it gives me just the name from the first . How to go to the second ?

thx

Comment: I suggest you to familiarize yourself with the concepts of DOM (Documenet Object Model). (TinyXML parses the xml-input into a DOM and offers means to traverse it).

Answer (score 0):

Use `NextSibling` or `NextSiblingElement` to get to the next element on the same hierarchy of the current subtree of the DOM.

All siblings are linked together and calling `NextSibling` on the last of them will return `NULL`. Assuming you have the first child element and want to run some code on it and on all of its siblings, it could looks like this:

```
TiXmlElement* element = ... (first child element)
do {
    // process the current element
}
// try to advance to the next sibling, break the loop if there is none.
while((element = element->NextSiblingElement()) != NULL);
```

Comment: can you show me how to do it? do i have to add at the end of .FirstChild("name").NextSiblingElement()?

Comment: what if firstly i would like to run the first <value></value> and after that to run the second <value></value>? i am asking this because i put in a list the elements from the <value> </value>. thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead of the last 3 lines of your code:

```
TiXmlElement* xml = handle.FirstChildElement("xml");

TiXmlElement* value = xml->FirstChildElement("value");
while (value)
{
    TiXmlElement* section = value->FirstChildElement("name");
    if (section) 
    {
        //code 
    }
    value = value->NextSiblingElement("value");
}
```

Actually you should check, if the results of `value->FirstChildElement("name")` and `handle->FirstChildElement("xml")` are not NULL.

Comment: i have error: invalid convertion from xml node to element. why?

Comment: Sorry, no C++ compiler available right now. But I suppose replacing all occurrences of `FirstChild` with `FirstChildElement` would help. I changed the sample above to do so.